# Alignment issue with \overline{x}

Tags: math-mode

I used LaTeX to write a document, and I was writing complex conjugates, so I had to make line a line on top of each number like this

```
       \overline X\cdot\overline y
```

But there's an alignment issue with the line on top of them. How to fix that?

Comment: Does `\overline{x \vphantom y} \cdot \overline y` solve the problem?

Comment: @ArunDebray oh yes, never thought of using \vphantom (always thought about \phantom as being horizontal, not vertical) please write answer to accept it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure what alignment issue you're talking about, because the overlines are at the same height. Are you thinking to `a` and `b`, rather than `x` and `y`?

Comment: @egreg just giving an example, or like `\overline{X}\cdot\overline{z}`

Comment: I prefer using `\bar`, usually; if the characters have different height, then the bar will be at different height.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\vphantom` to ensure they have the same heights:

```
\overline{x \vphantom y} \cdot \overline y
```

`\vphantom y` adds the vertical space of a `y`, but no horizontal space.